# Zenbu returning blank screen or no results on channel filter

Tags: control-panel, blank-screen, zenbu

We have a saved search in Zenbu that looks like:

?D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=zenbu&channel_id=14

This has started returning a blank page, though it doesn't take more than 2 seconds to return that.

I'm not seeing any memory or CPU spikes on the server or real degradation in performance. The site does have a lot of channel entries, most of which incorporate Structure as well as Zoo Visitor members. (The latter is the channel the saved search is looking for.)

If I use the "Channel is" filter in the Zenbu screen on a small channel, I get back results immediately. If I use it on the Zoo Visitor Members channel, I'm getting no results now. Same goes for one of my larger channels. I get no results back, but it's not timing out. It's instant.

I've checked recent entries and am seeing no issues in the data that would have caused this to suddenly occur.

What has me most confused is the sequence of events:

1. I received an email this morning, sent by my client last night, that he was seeing this behavior.
2. I logged in this morning and did not see this behavior. I accessed the screen and pulled up the latest entry.
3. I asked my client to clarify and he described the blank screen. I logged in again and saw the same thing.

These entries *do* appear in All Channels, just not in filtered views, which further implies that data is not the culprit.

Has anyone run into this or would know where to look?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue - did you ever find a solution ? Other than removing / renaming the Zenbu plugin folder ?

Comment: I'm coming up short on searching my email for the resolution on this. I had disabled it on Production at one point, and when I restored it to troubleshoot, it was working again. I never saw any memory or CPU spikes associated with Zenbu requests, though this client has had some issues with Edit screens loading based on characters in the Title field.